# Why is my Imenu not showing function and class definitions?

Tags: python, imenu

I feel like something is wrong with my Imenu setup, because here is what it shows on a simple Python script:

[image]

It seems to show some variable definitions, but doesn't have separate entries for the function definitions (the `def ...` lines), or the classes. What I want is an Imenu that shows just the function and class definitions, in the order in which they appear. So, I want to see something like:

```
Function: foo(x)
Class: Bar
Function: Bar / __init__(s)
Function: Bar / buz(x, y)
```

Is that possible at all? Semantic is not an option because it does not parse functions that are typed using Python's type annotations (e.g. a function like `def foo() -> None: ...` does not appear in the list).

Comment: Can you share your `imenu` configuration? Are you using a LSP, or maybe elpy? Please share more information.

Comment: I am using LSP, yes, but I have `lsp-ui-imenu-enable nil` and no other imenu-related entries in my init.el

Answer (score 2):

For any imenu problem, check the buffer's how-to-generate-imenu status (which is usually modified by major-mode, sometimes also some minor modes), mostly variable `imenu-create-index-function` and `imenu-generic-expression`:

- if `imenu-create-index-function` is `imenu-default-create-index-function`, which is Emacs default, the imenu is generated by running the regexps in `imenu-generic-expression` against buffer content, then you only need to tweak the regexps.
- if `imenu-create-index-function` is NOT `imenu-default-create-index-function`, then you need to dive into the actual value of `imenu-create-index-function` (which is a function, probably written and set by major mode) to see what's actually going wrong.

Comment: How do I check the how-to-generate-imenu status?

Comment: <kbd>C-h v</kbd> (`describe-variable`) to check the values of the 2 variables I mentioned above (also read the documents there, which along with my answer above should give you the idea of how imenu works).

Answer (score 0):

This is lsp-mode issue, which was reported and closed as wont fix. I have a better idea of how to fix it, so you may open issue lsp-mode bug tracker.

Comment: I just posted an issue, https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2246